# ldap search in java - finding all groups with a specific user in it

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

Given the below ldap structure (more or less)

```
C=NO
-o=mydomain
--cn=groups
---cn=group1
----uid=bob,cn=users,o=mydomain,C=NO
---cn=group2
----uid=bob,cn=users,o=mydomain,C=NO
----uid=odd,cn=users,o=mydomain,C=NO
--cn=users
---uid=bob,cn=Robert,sn=Johnsen
---uid=odd,cn=Odd,sn=Olsen
```

I use the following url= ldap://server:port/o=mydomain,C=NO

Then I can retrieve basically the entire tree with a search somewhat like this:

```
NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search("cn=groups", "cn=*", constraints);
```

where constraints is

```
constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

However, I'd like to receive only the groups with a specific user in it. I've tried lots and lots of variants like

```
        NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search("cn=groups"
                , "(&(uid={0},cn=users,o=fund,C=NO)(cn=*))"
                        , new Object[] {"odd"}
                        , constraints);
```

but I get only empty results. All or nothing it seems... I suspect the problem is that cn=* and uid=odd are on different levels in the tree, eg. uid=is an attribute, but cn=* is a node one level above?

How would I go about to complete this search in a more effective manner than just retrieving everything and parse it clientside?

Answer (score 1):

Your LDAP structure looks strange.

what is the class of objects like `cn=group1` ? is this "organizationalUnit" or "group"?

In usual Directories users are created under objects based on the "organizationalUnits" class, and for administrative needs they are grouped in an attribute called "member" of objects of the class "group".

In this case the LDAP filter would be like :

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=uid={0},cn=users,o=fund,C=NO))
```

With the architecture you discribe you may have a look to a feature called **ExtensibleMatch** which seems to be correctly explained in [this wiki article](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) .

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I dug out something similar from the net myself. objectClass=accessGroup, and the structure is legacy.